# How to display all the dates of the particular month

Tags: php, date

Code Used

```
$date_from1 = new DateTime('1-9-2016');
$date_from=$date_from1->format('Y-m-d');
$date_to1 = new DateTime('30-9-2016');
$date_to=$date_to1->format('Y-m-d');
$diff1=$date_from1->diff($date_to1);
$diff2= $diff1->format('%R %a days');
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $diff2, $matches); //use that to get only number from diff2
for($i=0; $i <= $matches[0][0]; $i++) //$matches return diff2 only number of days
{
    $this_date=$date_from1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    echo $this_date->format('Y-m-d') . "<br/>";
}
```

My output

> 2016-09-02 2016-09-03 2016-09-04 2016-09-05 2016-09-06 2016-09-07
>   2016-09-08 2016-09-09 2016-09-10 2016-09-11 2016-09-12 2016-09-13
>   2016-09-14 2016-09-15 2016-09-16 2016-09-17 2016-09-18 2016-09-19
>   2016-09-20 2016-09-21 2016-09-22 2016-09-23 2016-09-24 2016-09-25
>   2016-09-26 2016-09-27 2016-09-28 2016-09-29 2016-09-30 2016-10-01

Expected output

> 2016-09-01 2016-09-02 2016-09-03 2016-09-04 2016-09-05 2016-09-06
>   2016-09-07 2016-09-08 2016-09-09 2016-09-10 2016-09-11 2016-09-12
>   2016-09-13 2016-09-14 2016-09-15 2016-09-16 2016-09-17 2016-09-18
>   2016-09-19 2016-09-20 2016-09-21 2016-09-22 2016-09-23 2016-09-24
>   2016-09-25 2016-09-26 2016-09-27 2016-09-28 2016-09-29 2016-09-30
>                                                                                                                                               I cannot use *cal_days_in_month* as I have a date range and have to calculate  the number of days between the dates  selected.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close. You just need to change your loop so that `$this_date` equals `$date_from1` on the first iteration.

Change:

```
$this_date=$date_from1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

To:

```
$this_date= $i? $date_from1->add(new DateInterval('P1D')): $date_from1;
```

Sidenote: Your code is wasteful because you create a `new DateInterval` with the same value many times. You will improve your efficiency if you create the date interval once before the loop:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
```

And then just use that in each iteration of the loop:

```
$this_date= $i? $date_from1->add($interval): $date_from1;
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/uA8jU)

Comment: $this_date= $i? $date_from1->add($interval): $date_from1; is not working getting an error :Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: @nkh I've added a link at the bottom of my answer to show you my code running live. The error you just mentioned is not caused by my changes. I don't use the function `format()` anywhere in my solution.  It's coming from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I have used the code given by you still it is not working giving me an error                          Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: @nkh I suggest you open another question or just add to this question by sharing the whole script that generates the error.